# Set cookies before subsequent requests in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I'm trying to set some cookies (via javascript) before the browser makes a request for various resources lower on the page. The following works in Chrome/Firefox, but, not IE:

[some_page.html]

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script>
    var hash=new Date();
    document.cookie='hash=' + hash + ';';
    console.log("From page: " + hash);
</script>
<script src="/test_cookie.php"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

[test_cookie.php]

```
console.log('From script: <?=$_COOKIE['hash']?>');
```

When viewing some_page.html, I see the following in the console (in Chrome/Firefox):

```
"From page: 1316757967982"
"From script: 1316757967982"
```

Are there any tricks to get this to work in IE? Like setting `defer` on the `test_cookie.php` script tag, or, something else along those lines...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dynamically generate the second script tag and inject it into the page so there's no way it could start before you had set the cookie.  Then, if you're going to dynamically generate the script tag, it might actually be even better to add "?hash=1316757967982" onto the end of the test_cookie.php src URL so you could be guaranteed that your server gets the hash value (from the URL rather than the cookie).  Then, you don't have to rely on cookie vs. script timing.

Here's how you dynamically add a script tag:

```
function addScriptTag(url) {
  var s = document.createElement(’script’);
  s.type=’text/javascript’;
  s.src= url;
  document.getElementsByTagName(’head’)[0].appendChild(s);
} 

addScriptTag("/test_cookie.php?hash=" + new Date());
```

There is no contract with the browser that it won't start loading multiple scripts at the same time, there's only a contract that it will execute statically defined scripts in sequential order so I don't think your current approach is ever guaranteed to work.  Loading multiple scripts in parallel could easily be a desired browser speedup option.

Comment: Yes, you're probably correct that there's no spec'd contract, however, all current browsers (FF/IE/WK) will parse/execute an inline script before continuing to parse the rest of the DOM. See: http://bit.ly/q4Ku19 http://bit.ly/pkcCK3. 

Also, dynamically adding a script won't preserve execution order, right? Sorry, I should have specified that as a requirement...

Comment: By contract all code in the page has to be executed in order and DOM elements before it in the page have to exist when it's executed.  But, code doesn't have to be fetched from the server in any specific order which is what you are trying to rely on.  So, I don't think you can rely on that.  You are correct that a dynamically inserted script tag is now asynchronously loaded so no load/execution order is guarenteed.

Comment: If you want more options for solving your problem, you probably need to explain what you're really trying to do here.  Why do you need to get a hash value into a cookie before a script is loaded.  There are probably different ways to solve that problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's important to understand that IE has a speculative download engine that "looks ahead" of the parsing process for things to download. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/18/optimal-html-head-ordering-to-avoid-parser-restarts-redownloads-and-improve-performance.aspx Other browsers also have lookaheads, but they are not necessarily as effective.

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken in my original testing. Thanks for the responses, all!